# Generic mouse button remapping utility/driver

Tags: drivers, mouse, remapping

I'm looking for a generic utility/driver that allows me some basic mouse button remapping; especially setting the thumb button as "middle button" and maybe even the wheel button as "double click".

I would use Logitech's driver but hey, they apparently don't think it's important to support their older mice in the Windows7-compatible SetPoint software.

I'm pretty sure there's some open source (not a requirement though) mouse driver out there which acts like Microsoft's default moue driver but allows button remapping. However, I couldn't find such a driver when searching (most results pointed to forums where less-technical people asked and just got "get your vendor's driver" answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) is your friend. :)

First, you will need AHK itself. Download it from the website (first link). It's free of charge, no registration, etc.

Then, create a new AHK script, with a .ahk ending.
Using the online [tutorial](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm) (and manuals) will help you figure out most of the things.

[Remapping keys](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm).